# Samba speed on Wi-Fi is atrocious

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, samba

I have two computers (desk and laptop), both running Arch Linux, and the desk computer has a few Samba shares.

The desktop machine is connected via cable to the router; and the laptop is mostly on Wi-Fi.

The desktop machine is running a Samba server, and I use it to watch videos on my laptops or on my Raspberry Pi (which is connected by cable).

When working with a cable-connected machine, the videos stream flawlessly, and everything is fine. When working with the Wi-Fi, videos are often very slow, and if I try to copy the file locally the speed gets to a few hundred kb/s at best (while on cable it utilizes the full 100mb/s of the cable).

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Solving Wi-Fi performance problems requires a lot of technical information about your Wi-Fi equipment, how it's configured, and what RSSI levels and PHY rates you're getting. You should edit your question to give us the data we need to determine what data rate you *should* be getting.

Comment: I'd be happy to oblige, but I don't know exactly what is the information needed here. I should probably add that even if I'm sitting right next to the router, and downloads and YouTube works at full speed, copying files over Samba still works excruciatingly slow.

Comment: We need to know the a/b/g/n/ac flavors supported, the number of spatial streams supported, and the bands (2.4 or 5GHz) supported by both the AP and the client. Sometimes it's just easier to tell us the exact make and model of your AP and your wireless NIC and let us look up the details. We need to know what RSSI (signal strength, in negative dBm) your client gets from the AP in this location, and what PHY rate your client reports. An iperf test would help too (note: iperf client sends by default, so run iperf in client mode on desktop Samba server, and server mode on wireless laptop).